# Parsing Ambiguous Dates in R

Tags: r, date

I want to know how to find out which part of string is month and which part of string is day while parsing dates.

The problem is 01-06-2017 can be 1 June or it can be 6 January. How to parse it correctly. In India we write dates as Day Month Year mostly, in west it is Month Day Year mostly, when I have mixed data how do I impute which is the month and which is the day

because the data is not clean enough, it sometimes have dates in mdy and sometimes in dmy format and if the number is less than 12, it is difficult to know if it is a day or a month

11/1/11 can be 11 Jan 2011 or 1 November 2011

Example

I am using lubridate package and I have dates in this format

```
 library(lubridate)
fundates2=c("1Apr2017","12-30-2017","1/6/17")

    fun3=dmy(fundates2)
## Warning: 1 failed to parse.
    fun3
## [1] "2017-04-01" NA           "2017-06-01"
fun4=mdy(fundates2)
## Warning: 1 failed to parse.
fun4
## [1] NA           "2017-12-30" "2017-01-06"
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please add some more code so that people can clearly see what your problem is? To be honest, I still don't get why you need to know which part of your string represents day and month. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have yo know from your context which one is the correct.

To check which one your date is you can simply add 1 day to it:

- In `fun3`:

  fun3 + 1

  [1] "2017-04-02" NA           "2017-06-02"

You can see that the month is the 06.

- In `fun4`:

  fun4 + 1

  [1] NA           "2017-12-31" "2017-01-07"

You can see the month is 01